# How can I check if a specific process is running on a remote PC/Server?

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

```
string ComputerName = serverName;
ManagementScope Scope;

if (!ComputerName.Equals("localhost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    ConnectionOptions Conn = new ConnectionOptions();
    Conn.Username = "";
    Conn.Password = "";
    Conn.Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN";
    Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), Conn);
}
else
    Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), null);

Scope.Connect(); // CRASH HERE
ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process Where Name='" + processName + "'");
ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);
```

The message that shows up is:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: Are the credentials correct? Why do you add `null` as a parameter in the constructor in the `else` clause? According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.management.managementscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx , you can just leave it out. Also, can you give a more detailed stacktrace, where exactly in the internal function it crashes?

Comment: It was crashing at Scope.Connect (I commented it in the code)

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely to do with wrong credentials or insufficient permissions. In your case no username provided - I am fairly sure you cannot pass empty username. The username/password you use for WMI query have to exist on the remote PC (plus the user has to have sufficient permissions).

If you want to use the same username/password you are logged in with on the local PC (from which you are running the code), you should omit the whole ConnectionOptions part:

```
    //ConnectionOptions Conn = new ConnectionOptions();
    //Conn.Username = "";
    //Conn.Password = "";
    //Conn.Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN";
```

I tried your code (added last 4 lines for testing) and it came up with the same error as you have. Once I added username and password everything is running fine.

```
string ComputerName = "10.1.2.3";
ManagementScope Scope;

if (!ComputerName.Equals("localhost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    ConnectionOptions Conn = new ConnectionOptions();
    Conn.Username = "Administrator";
    Conn.Password = "pass123";
    //Conn.Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN";
    Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), Conn);
}
else
    Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), null);

Scope.Connect(); // CRASH HERE
ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process Where Name='" + "cmd.exe" + "'");
ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);

ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = Searcher.Get();

foreach (var item in queryCollection)
    Console.WriteLine(item["Description"]);

Console.Read();
```

I also tried the same code with the section regarding ConnectionOptions commented out and it also works. Note, however, that according to what I wrote earlier, I had to create a user on the remote PC, which has the same credentials as the user I am logged in on the local PC.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Also as per Maximilian Gerhardt comment, skip NULL this line:

```
Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), null);
```